# How to give permissions to a user in my account in unix

Tags: unix

i am sudo user and i copied files from one user account to another user's account and i gave permissions like

```
              sudo chmod 777 ..../*.*
```

but it is giving like

```
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7168 2011-04-26 10:44 test.db
        -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3826370 2011-04-26 10:44 libport.a
```

but when other user who has copied files,cant remove those files by giving

```
        rm test.db
        rm libport.a
```

so what should i do without installing any softwares?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try chgrp <your user> <which ever file>

Comment: you need write permissions on a directory to remove files from it.

Comment: I explain all about Unix File Permissions in the SU Blog: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/

Answer (score 2):

Creating and removing files in a directory requires write access to the *directory,* not the files themselves.

I should mention that, in the UNIX world, it is `777` which is the number of the beast rather than `666`. Setting your permissions to `777` is almost *always* a bad idea.

In addition, setting the permissions on files currently in existence has *zero* effect of files which will be created in the future. The permissions given to files are (when unspecified) determined by your `umask` setting.

Comment: I agree 777 is bad - data files should not be executable!  But the number of the beast is also bad; public write permission should normally be avoided (so 666 is not good; 664 or 644 is much better).

Answer (score 0):

To change ownership of files use:

```
sudo chown system_username / file_location
```

To change file permissions use:

```
sudo chmod 0777 (or the permissions you want) / file_location
```

Use the second command and apply it to the directory in which your copied files are placed. That will give file create & delete access inside that directory.